# Evolving magikarp

Tags: pokemon-go

So I have done the impossible and managed to catch 101 magikarp which gets me a little over 400 candies. I can now evolve him into a gyarados (which I'm super excited about!) but my question is about evolution CP points. Is there a calculator or equation to use to determine what CP the gyarados will be? I have worked really hard to gain 400+ candies and want to evolve my magikarp at the best possible time. Does anyone know the CP cap for a magikarp? I am a level 16 and my magikarp is 124CP points.

Comment: You can determine how high the CP is compared to the max CP for the Pokemon for your current level using the "arch" above them on their profile - the further to the right the dot is, the closer to max. It doesn't tell you numerically what the evolved value will be, but gives a hint as to whether it would be better to wait for a higher level Pokemon to evolve...